# Is there a limit on how big a varchar can be sent from Node.js to mssql?

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

I've created a JS/JQuery UI that connects to a Node.js service that processes the data before persisting it in a MS SQL Server database.

The application works fine, but the users needed more space in a comments field.  I had it as varchar(512), so I increased it to varchar(8000) (max for varchar in the SQL Server version my company is running).  When I submit a form with than than ~3700 characters in the comments field, the connection to the DB server resets with the error shown below.

However, if I copy the SQL statement from my server log and paste it into MS SQL Server Management Studio, the statement executes as expected with no error, which is why I've started to think it's a Node.js "mssql" module problem.

For now I'm going to set form validation on the field to 3500 characters, but it would be nice to not be limited by the module.

```
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET
    at ConnectionError (C:\Users\fw278e\Documents\GitRepo\lm_itar\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\fw278e\Documents\GitRepo\lm_itar\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:688:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fw278e\Documents\GitRepo\lm_itar\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:328:30)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\fw278e\Documents\GitRepo\lm_itar\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:688:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  message: 'Connection lost - read ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ESOCKET'
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are having a timeout due to the size of the payload you are trying to write in the database?

Comment: The error happens instantly.